# Keras Conv1D / time series

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

forgive me if my question is silly, I'm still quite a newbie. I want to experiment with time series prediction and a NN whose input is a 1-dimensional conv layer.

Now, as far as I understand it, the input shape is required to be (length feature set, num channels). In my model I have ~400k data points x 6 channels. I want to train - say - 100 data points into the past, which correspond to one label I'm trying to predict.

If I understand that correctly, I have to extract lots of feature sets ('slices') out of the original data, which I then apply to the model. For instance, [0 .. 99], [1 .. 100], [2 .. 101] and so on.

If I do this, my data explode into 100x the original size, since I have to provide views of 100 time stamps each.

Now my question: is there a way to tell the models input layer to 'cut' the single feature sets directly out of the whole time series? So, for training step 1, it uses [0 .. 99], for training step 2 it'll use [1 .. 100] and so on?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The Tensorflow [tutorial for time series](http://The%20Tensorflow%20tutorial%20for%20%5Btime%20series%5D(https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series?hl=en)%20has%20probably%20the%20state-of-the-art%20for%20this%20kind%20of%20operation.) has probably the state-of-the-art for this kind of operation in Keras/Tensorflow. However, I think what you want (in-model conversion into time slices) is currently not possible (2020-12-26). Tensorflow and Keras work with the [Dataset object](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) but it does support this kind of operation. Keras features a preprocessing API, which comes in handy for [time slicing](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/timeseries_dataset_from_array) etc. I suggest to follow the guidelines in the time series tutorial, it includes the creation of a class WindowGenerator, which suits your use case well, though data are not being processed inside the model.